# How to select/switch to dialog box without use mouse? (Tab button cannot work)

Tags: applescript

I have try to write AppleScript to move an app into trash. When I run the script it will pop up a dialog box. But the "Tab" key cannot switch to the dialog box (I need to use the mouse to click on it to select the dialog box). But I want to write the script to instead of use mouse action.

Is there have any shortcut can select/switch to the dialog box? or what is the correct script I should use?

```
tell application "Finder"
    
    delete file "Application Name" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
    
end tell
```

Comment: RE: "When I run the script it will pop up a dialog box." --  There is no _code_ shown in your question that generates a _dialog box_! -- That said, in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** make sure **[√] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** is checked.

Answer (score 0):

For example, in **macOS Catalina**, using **AppleScript** to display a *dialog box* and then be able to manually *tab* between the *controls* of a *dialog box*, one must have **[√] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** is checked in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**

Using a `display dialog` *command* at its least amount of *code*, i.e., `display dialog ""`, it presents a *dialog box* such as the following, in which I'm manually pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> *key*:

[image]

However, if the aforementioned *check box* is not checked, then the following image is what one gets, and as you can see neither *button* is highlighted and pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> *key* does nothing:

[image]